# java - replace key + values in hashmap with identical key + different values

Tags: java, hashmap

I have researched this question for ages and cannot get it right!

I have a populated hashmap and an identically formatted hashmap (`Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>>`) that I have been working on (it has key value/s equal to other keys in the populated hashmap such as 0,1,2 etc). When I use the .put command to update the populated hashmap the few/one I have been working on replaces everything in the populated hashmap - is this normal? Where am I going wrong? I was expecting it to simply replace the key in question + values....

Excuse the not supplying code but it would mean posting quite an amount to demonstrate, just wondering if anyone could help explain where this might be going wrong. I could throw something together to show if needed...

Much obliged!

Comment: I did not understand your question? Do you mean that when you put an already present key in the `map` why does it get replaced?

Comment: it would be good if you could just post the loop/replacement code in question

Comment: You will have to post code. Your question is quite incomprehensible and anyway, how could we know what you're doing wrong. Reduce your code to the minimum necessary to reproduce your problem, don't just dump everything you've got.

Comment: when you say the replacement key is identical, you mean exact same? If the key is different then you better remove the previous (key,value) pair and simply add the new one .put(identical_key,value)

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are asking. For example what is an "hasmap (Map>)", but my best guess is that there is something wrong with the equals() and hashcode() methods on the class that you use as keys.

Comment: sorry. It is for a booking system and after the creation of an account those details might need to be changed. updateMapLayout = hashmap with altered values but the same key values as their counterparts in mainMapLayout where all the other customer values are stored..

..when I use .put to add the updated map values (where I was expecting to simply replace keys with the same key values (eg 1,2,3)) it replaces everything (updateMapLayout replaces everything in mainMapLayout) so now mainMapLayout only has the values of the updated map (updateMapLayout).

Comment: I am not using a for loop or any such thing, it is a clean .put command in a method body...any better?

Comment: Ok, there is something fishy going on here. Providing code would possibly solve this fast. Are you sure that the two variables aren't pointing to the same object? That is are you either making a deep-copy of the original hashmap, or when adding elements adding them (with for example put()) to both HashMaps?

Comment: no, I have been using System.out.println to check the contents of both before and after attempting to add...

Comment: Please re-read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: The question is unclear. Please give a simple example: What is already in the map? What do you update and how? What would you expect as result? What do you get as result instead? I have the impression your map contains (1, List ("foo", "bar")) - you update (1, "foobar") and expect (1, List ("foo", "bar", "foobar")).

Comment: I expect:    contains (1, List ("foo", "bar")), I update (1, "foobar") and expect (1, List ("foobar"))

Comment: But then what happens? Apparently you don't get your expected (1, List("foobar")). What do you get instead?

Comment: well the list will have say {0=["foo", "bar"] 1=["java", "bar"]} then I use .put to add {0=["foobar"]} and now the list reads {0=["foobar"]}, 1=["java", "bar"] disappears....

Comment: I see. That shouldn't happen. Now, please post some code so we can help you. You've been asked to post your code a couple of times already.

Comment: I have been thinking and it is actually {string=[1=["foo", "bar"]2=["java", "bar"]}, when I use .put to add 1=["foobar"] the map now reads - {string=1=["foobar"]}

Comment: sorry, I will get on it, I am half seeing somewhere that I might be going wrong!

Comment: I can see how a `Map<String, Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>>>` could be confusing... Maybe you should just create some new, easier to handle object to do the work of that structure?

Comment: yeah, this is my lack of experience coming in, it isn't exactly the best to work with or most efficient structure but easy to understand in terms of how to find stuff....will see if I can get some code together but it is all over the place!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how a code example might look like:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumFormEx
{
    public static ArrayList <String> listIt (String... params) 
    {
        ArrayList <String> as = new ArrayList <String> ();
        for (String s: params)
            as.add (s);
        return as;
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Map <Integer, ArrayList<String>> mils = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> ();
        mils.put (1, listIt ("foo", "bar")); 
        mils.put (2, listIt ("zacka", "zacka")); 
        System.out.println ("mils:\t" + mils);
        mils.put (1, listIt ("foobar"));        
        System.out.println ("mils:\t" + mils);
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
java NumFormEx
mils:   {1=[foo, bar], 2=[zacka, zacka]}
mils:   {1=[foobar], 2=[zacka, zacka]}
```

I would say: as expected.

Comment: that does help, thanks! would you expect to be able to take the mils map and .put it into a Map<String, Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>>> to the same effect?

Comment: I don't quiet understand `to the same effect`. Yes, I could put that map into another map, where Strings are keys. Not that easy to imagine a use case, but you could have a mapping of words usages: John used 2 times "zacka zacka", 1 times "foo", 1 times "bar". Peter has a different usage-map. For different names we have different maps, maps get updated, inserted, removed ... . Can you build an example showing problems?

Answer (score 0):

Since map doesn't allow duplicate values you can do :

```
myMap.put(2, new ArrayList<String>());
```

This will take element with key 2 and replace it's list with new ("blank") list.

Comment: I have been using:

mainMapLayout.put(int, updateMapLayout);

I might have to correct myself as I am adding a Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> to Map<String, Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>>>. 

Map<String (for mainMapLayout) = user name and Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> for customer values (Integer = 0.1,2,3 etc and values = ArrayList<String>)

my apologies!

Comment: results, original file contents:        
2.d.title={0=[1, 2, 3,  , 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,  , 9, 10, 11], 1=[1, 2, 3,  , 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,  , 9, 10, 11]}}         

updated file contents:      
2.d.title={0=[1, 2, 3,  , 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,  , 9, x, 11]}}        

using command:        
mainMapLayout.put(string, updateMapLayout);